# How can I exclude results from a process count containing specific arguments?

Tags: regex, grep, ps, wc

I'm counting processes like so:

```
ps aux | grep my_script.php | grep -v grep | wc -l
```

But this includes results for both `my_script.php foo=1` as well as `my_script.php foo=1&bar=2`.

How can I separate these counts? I'd like to count how many include the argument `bar` separately from those who do not include `bar`.

Assuming the above `ps aux...` returns 2 (one with the argument `bar` and one without), how can I search for each one at a time?

Desired result: (with obvious fake placeholder for illustration)

```
// list all my_script.php processes
$ ps aux | grep my_script.php | grep -v grep
root  10 ... Ss  14:34 0:53 php /path/to/my_script.php foo=1&bar=2
root  12 ... Ss  14:35 0:46 php /path/to/my_script.php foo=1
// returns 2 lines (this works)

// Just count just those including the `bar` argument
$ ps aux | grep my_script.php _____+bar_____ | grep -v grep | wc -l
// return 1

// Just count only those NOT including the `bar` argument
$ ps aux | grep my_script.php _____-bar_____ | grep -v grep | grep -v bar | wc -l
// return 1
```

**UPDATE**

I can crudely exclude `bar` results like so:

```
$ ps aux | grep my_script.php | grep -v grep | grep -v bar | wc -l
```

Obviously that won't work for times when the script name or path may include `bar` string, but for now it works for me. The main thing I'm after is how to count the opposite. That is, how to count those only including the `bar`.

Comment: `grep [m]yscript.php` will avoid the need to `grep -v grep`. You also probably want `[m]yscript\\.php` to match a literal `.`.

Comment: Add more to your pattern or use multiple grep passes to get the different counts. Your placeholders are basically what you need (when rewritten as grep patterns).

Comment: Right, I can actually get those that include `bar` just fine. I just include `grep -v bar`. But how can I get the opposite?

Comment: `grep -v bar` will *exclude* those that have the word `bar` in it. `grep bar` will *include* the ones that have `bar` in them.

Comment: And you might want to look into `pgrep`.

Comment: Shoot, sorry, I meant the opposite. But you're exactly correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this help?

```
ps aux|grep -Pc 'my_script[.]ph[p].*[\s&]bar='
```

- `-P` use perl regex
- `[.]` make it match literal dot, not any single character
- `ph[p]` filter the `grep` process itself out
- `[\s&]bar=` this matches an empty or `&` + `bar=`
- `-c` return you only the number of matched lines

an example, (text file to simulate your ps output):

```
kent$  cat f
root  10 ... Ss  14:34 0:53 php /path/to/my_script.php foo=1&bar=2
root  12 ... Ss  14:35 0:46 php /path/to/my_script.php foo=1
root  12 ... Ss  14:35 0:46 php /path/to/my_script.php foobar=1
root  12 ... Ss  14:35 0:46 php /path/to/my_script.php bar=1

kent$  grep -Pc 'my_script[.]ph[p].*[&\s]bar=' f
2
```